# How to not duplicate files for each language on a multilingual website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, multilingual

I'm currently working on a website that it meant to be translated in multiple languages. I've did a lot of research but I might have missed something because I really don't get ho my structure should be organised.

To put some context in, my website is developed using html, css, js + jquery, has a MySQL database and use a Java EE backend as a rest API to fetch data from the database.

I would like the urls to look like this (as suggested on a lot of websites) :

```
www.example.com/fr/page1
www.example.com/en/page1
```

But does it means my file directory should look like this?

```
index.html  
fr/  
----index.html  
----page1.html  
----page2.html  
en/  
----index.html  
----page1.html  
----page2.html  
js/  
----page1.js  
----page2.js
```

If so, then I need to copy my index.html (and every other page) in every single language directory. This seems very bad since every time I will have to change something in the code, I will have to change it in every single files...

What I would love to have is just one copy of each files (index.html, page1.html, etc) then a file containing all translations for each language and then use these files to populate the html template.
The structure being something like this :

```
index.html  
page1.html  
page2.html  
language/  
----fr.json  
----en.json  
js/  
----page1.js  
----page2.js
```

Something simple like that. In this example I would only have a copy of each files but then how to work with the url to still make it like www.example.com/fr/page1 even though there isn't such directories?

I don't know if all of this makes sense, I'm pretty new to this and I'm really lost with this multilingual website problem... I would like to make it the cleanest way possible to be able to expand it to other languages later really easily.

Comment: You could store the translations in your database and then pull the requisite language based on the URL.  There are services that do this too like POEdit but I believe it is a subscription based service.

Comment: Are you writing HTML files or JSP files?  I would expect JSP to have some sort of i18n mechanism.  If you are writing **just** HTML files though, you need to rethink your approach.  You want to define the structure and then pull in the translated data to populate the template or semi-concrete "page" that knows where to plug the translated data.

Comment: You should have a look at how some high level frameworks deal with multilingual support.  Consider how [AEM](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-5/sites/developing/using/i18n-translator.html) makes you write translation dictionaries and then you can use references to the topic in your JSP/HTL which will populate with the correct translation content depending on which language you are viewing.  It's a big topic, but the concept you should be exploring is i18n.